# Making a CSS margin responsive

Tags: html, css

I have a span, defined as:

```
<span class="loginRegisterBtn" style="text-decoration: none; color: black; font-size: 20px; margin-top: 50px; margin-right: 10px;" href="/register"><a href="/login" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;">LOGIN</a> | <a href="/register" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;">REGISTER</a></span>
```

Also, I added some additional styles to the span:

```
.loginRegisterBtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

And it has a margin-top of 50px. When on a normal laptop or desktop, it is positions where I want it to be, but when the screen is put to the size of a phone, or shrunk to a certain width, it begins to overlap with another component of the website, the title, defined above the span, defined as so:

```
<a href="/" style="text-decoration: none; color: black"><h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 60px; position: relative; top: 15px; color: #413f3d;"><strong>Crabapple Lake Parc</strong></h1></a>
```

I want the margins to be responsive so that they don't overlap each other when the screen size is adjusted. I tried to make the margin use the `vw`, but that did not work. I looked at other answers on this site, and none of them answered my question.

Comment: `vw` margins definitely work, try resizing the preview window here: https://jsfiddle.net/3z16vxog/

Comment: @Leland look at my edit, i forgot to include the external CSS, because when I try `vw`, it still is overlapping the title.

Comment: the style defined at `.loginRegisterBtn` is the reason why the overlap happen in the first place, margin itself works the same regardless of the device displaying the page

Comment: @Kazz So how would I implement a fix?

Comment: remove `position: absolute;`

Comment: @Kazz That is better but it puts it on the to left and I want it on the top right

Comment: generally `position: absolute;` is used when you want that element to overlap something, you could possibly use that with combination of media queries but its ugly, hard to maintain and bad design which broke easily, unfortunately its also the only way to make it responsible. so you should use something else to get it to the top right position, something which works with relative positioning that way it wont overlap something else, the best candidates are imo: flexbox or floating

Answer (score 0):

Your mixing of inline `style`'s and separate CSS, and various nested (but unrelated) elements makes your issue hard to actually reckon with. I recommend next time that you produce a single, easy to see example of HTML and CSS so that SO users can interact with your problem.

Here I've separated out all inline styles, and removed anything related to presentation, so we can focus just on position:

```css
.title {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
}

.loginRegisterBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Crabapple Lake Parc</h1>

<span class="loginRegisterBtn">REGISTER | LOGIN</span>
```

Your issue can be restated as: "`.loginRegisterBtn` will cover up `.title` at certain screen sizes".

Normally, with CSS, that's not possible: elements aren't able to be on top of each other by default. The reason for that here is because of `position: absolute;`, which lets you put an element wherever you want, even if it intersects with another one. I presume you chose to use that because you want the element in the top right.

There are a few ways to have an element there without having them overlap your title. One way is with [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Here's how I might do that:

```css
.titleHeader {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<header class="titleHeader">
  <h1 class="title">Crabapple Lake Parc</h1>

  <span class="loginRegisterBtn">REGISTER | LOGIN</span>
</header>
```

The elements now peacefully co-exist, and they'll never overlap. You can now add spacing properties to this, and it won't cause your issue.

---

Edit: if you want the text centered, and the login text to appear to the right of it, you'll need to use `absolute` positioning. In order to accommodate small screens, we can just use media queries, instead:

```css
.titleWrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
}

.loginRegisterBtn {
  text-align: right;
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .loginRegisterBtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="titleWrapper">
  <div class="loginRegisterBtn">REGISTER | LOGIN</div>

  <h1 class="title">Crabapple Lake Parc</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: All is good, just wondering how to align the title to the center?

Comment: Hm... If you want the title centered, and the login/register right-aligned, what is your expectation for what should happen at small screens, when the two can no longer fit side-by-side?

Comment: I've tried to accommodate this in my post with a new edit :)